# Where should I handle concurrent operations on the same data? In the application or the database?

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions, synchronization

So I am building a Java webapp with Spring and Hibernate. In the application userw can add points to a object and I'd like to count the points given to order my objects. The objects are also stored in the database. And hopefully hundreds of people will give points to the objects at the same time.

But how do I count the points and save them in the database at the same time? Usually I would just have a property on my object and just increase the points. But that would mean that I have to lock the data in the database with a pessimistic transaction in order to prevent concurrency issues (reading the amount of points while another thread is half way through changing it already). That would possibly make my app much slower (at least I imagine it would).

The other solution would be to store the amount of given points in an associated object and store them separately in the database while counting the points in memory within a "small" synchronized block or something.

Which solution has the least performance impact when handling many concurrent operations on the same objects. Or are there any other fitting solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the values to be persisted, then you should persist them in your database.

Given that, try the following:

1. create a very narrow row, like just OBJ_ID and POINTS.
2. create an index only on OBJ_ID, so not a lot of time is spent updating indexes when values are inserted, updated or deleted.
3. use INNODB, which has row-level locking, so the locks will be smaller
4. mysql will give you the last committed (consistent) value

That's all pretty simple.  Give a whirl!  Setup a test case that mimics your expected load and see how it performs.  Post back if you get stuck.

Good luck.

Comment: Ok that sounds reasonable but you said that mysql will give me the last committed value. What happens if two requests read this value at the same time and try to write a new value to the db? will the last one to write get an error or will the transaction prevent the second request from continuing with the execution until the first request is finished?

Comment: start the transaction, read the value, write the incremented value, commit the transaction.  All safe.